# Obtengo "TypeError: 'int' does not support indexing" en loop while. Python 3

Tags: python, while

La función es simple, si las primeras 2 cifras de un número de 4 dígitos se repiten, debe generarse otro número a travez de la función `randint()` hasta que estas sean distintas pero  me salta este error en el loop while:  "TypeError: 'int' does not support indexing in line...".

Este es el código:

```
from random import randint


num = 1123
#convierto el integer en una lista
num = list(map(int, str(num)))

while num[0] == num[1]:
  num = randint(1000,9999)
  print(num)
```

Si utilizo un condicional `if` este error no aparece, pero tampoco vuelve a verificar que el nuevo número generado no cumpla con esta condición. ¿Donde está el problema aquí?

Comment: Cristianjs19, el se debe a que un valor entero **no se puede recorrer**, no tiene posiciones; No es iterable. Prueba con **while str(num)[0] == str(num)[1]:**. Eso convertirá a cadena de caracteres la variable num, y así podras sub indicarla.

Comment: Dentro del ciclo `while` reasignas `num`, asignándole un entero, la salida de `randint` (`num = randint(1000,9999)`,), por lo que en la segunda iteración `num` no apunta a una lista y tienes el error. Debes generar la lista dentro del `while`, añadiendo `num = list(map(int, str(num)))` debajo de `randint`, o trabaja con una cadena simplemente, como comenta Rodrigo. No necesitas convertir a lista de enteros realmente.

Comment: @FJSevilla Exacto...! vaya como no lo ví. Creo que ya estaba mareado dentro de lo que era el programa entero (esto era un extracto, claro). Gracias amigo... Creas la respuesta y le doy el OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tu ciclo `while` inicia la variable `num` hace referencia a una lista de enteros gracias a `num = list(map(int, str(num)))`, por lo que la primera iteración (si llega a producirse, porque los dos primeros dígitos sean iguales) no tiene problemas.

El error se produce en la segunda iteración, dentro del `while` reasignas `num` al hacer `num = randint(1000, 9999)`. Esto hace que a partir de ahora `num` apunte a un objeto `int` y no a una lista por lo que en la segunda iteración, cuando se evalua `num[0] == num[1]` tienes el error mencionado, dado que intenta indexar sobre un entero.

La solución simple es volver a genera la lista dentro del ciclo:

```
num = 1123

num = list(map(int, str(num)))

while num[0] == num[1]:
  num = randint(1000, 9999)
  num = list(map(int, str(num)))
```

No obstante, dos apuntes:

- Si luego vas a necesitar el entero, vas a tener que volver a pasar de la lista de dígitos a un `int`. En lugar de hacer esto, considera usar dos variables, una que almacene el entero y otra que te sirva para la comparación.
- No necesitas realmente una lista con todos los dígitos, basta con usar una cadena y comparar los dos primeros caracteres como sugiere @RodrigoN en su comentario. Aunque la comparación es lexicográfica, en este caso no hay problemas, porque solo miras que sean o no iguales, además de que solo comparas un dígito con otro. Esto te ahorra iterar sobre la cadena, crear un objeto `int` por cada dígito y una lista para contenerlos.

En definitiva, puedes hacer algo así:

```
from random import randint


num = 1123

str_num = str(num)
while str_num[0] == str_num[1]:
  num = randint(1000, 9999)
  str_num = str(num)

print(num)
```